# Only add class metadata for non-concrete types in Genson

Tags: java, genson

So I can do the following `new GensonBuilder().useClassMetadata(true)` and Genson will add a `@Class` element to the Json Object with the class name when it serializes.

Is there any way I can have this happen only when it comes to a runtime type that is different to compile time.

E.g.

```
class MyType {

    public MyType myType;
    public Objct myType2;
}
```

I would expect a `@Class` element on `myType2` when serialized, but not `myType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at the moment there is no such option.
You could easily implement your use case by modifying [ClassMetadataConverter](https://github.com/owlike/genson/blob/master/genson/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/convert/ClassMetadataConverter.java). If you do it, it might be great to make a PR with your changes.

**Update** In latest Genson release 1.1, you have now an option in the builder to enable this behaviour:

```
new GensonBuilder().useClassMetadataWithStaticType(false).create();
```

Comment: I did have a quick look into this but it didn't look like I'd have what was required to achieve this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok, I have created an issue for your use case https://github.com/owlike/genson/issues/17, see if the description helps you to implement it. Don't hesitate to ask there for help to implement it.

Comment: Ah didn't see that `tClass` was available...will have a hack around soon - thanks.

Comment: I am getting a `"val$scanner":{}` on everything I serialize, I get the same in version 1.1 too.

Comment: Can you please post an example on genson mailing list?